# Get JSON data stored in a hidden input element?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm building a website that store json data to hidden input element with php

```
<input type='hidden' class='json_data' name='json_data' value='".json_encode($data[0])."'>
```

with that code, I have this result:

```
<input class="json_data" type="hidden" value="[{"ALBUM_ID":"1234","PHOTOS_ID":"1234578"}]" name="json_data">
```

but when I try to get the value with jquery.val and trying to show ALBUM_ID, i get this `{`

anything wrong with my way of putting json into html correctly?

and then get it with jquery / javascript ?

thanks

Comment: May be because of `"` inside `"`

Comment: i did `htmlspecialchars` but still get the same result.

Comment: Why are you putting this in an hidden input and not just adding a script tag to the page with the value?

Comment: because the data will be save to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First go ahead at this open console and see the result. Ctl+Shift+j.

**http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/Q2MHA/**

You need to do two things fix. `'` and `"`'

Second just this code

`JSON.parse($('.json_data').val())[0]`

you need [0] because for some reason your json object is wrapped in []..you would know why.

Your html should look like this

`<input ... value='[{"ALBUM_ID":"1234","PHOTOS_ID":"1234578"}]'...>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to correctly handle entities in your `input`'s `value`. If you populate it with PHP, use `htmlspechalchars()` and use result from this function

Comment: i did do that. `htmlspecialchars(json_encode($data))` but still get the `{`

Answer (score 1):

inspect the following line carefully.

```
<input class="json_data" type="hidden" value="[{"ALBUM_ID":"1234","PHOTOS_ID":"1234578"}]" name="json_data">
```

As you see you have used `"` for your string enclosement. The json string also includes `"` which breaks your string enclosement. Use `'` to enclose the string.

```
<input class="json_data" type="hidden" value='[{"ALBUM_ID":"1234","PHOTOS_ID":"1234578"}]' name="json_data">
```

Comment: And when the value has a `'` in it? Breaks once again!

Comment: @epascarello what if json string include ' and " both.What to do in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the " with addslashes or htmlspecialchars

or encode the string with base64 and decode it with JS before parsing the string as JSON